# asssembly output -S switch of gcc. Then through gnu assembler i generate the object code. and now i have to link via ld

Tags: assembly, static, gnu, ld, static-linking

How to use static linking? I have done this using dynamic standard library in Linux.
I put -S switch of gcc. Then through gnu assembler I generated the object code. And now i have to  link via Ld (statically).

Please show me how?

Comment: You can use `gcc -v` to see how the compiler invokes `ld`. Just copy that. Beware, it isn't pretty :)

Comment: You shouldn't even need to use `ld` explicitly - just use `gcc` as your driver and add the appropriate static linking switches.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the ar utility.  First use 'as' to create .obj files for each function you want in the library.

Then use the ar utility to creat the library:

```
    $> ar -r your-lib-name.a func1.o func2.o func3.o
```

On linux the .a extension is used to identify static libraries.

Check the library to see what was created:

```
    $> ar -t your-lib-name.a
```

Finally, you should use the utility 'ranlib' to create an index for the library.  This will speed up compilation for programs that need to link with the library.  The index is put in the library file.

```
    $> ranlib your-lib-name.a
```

also look at the 'nm' utility if you want to disply the library index.